# How to Parse JSON in Feedzilla API

Tags: database, json, parsing, feedzirra

Hi am working on FeedZilla API for data access in JASON format. I am getting the response but unable to show it. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
                //url:"http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json?q=Michael",
                url:"http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles.json",
                type:'GET',
        //      data:'value='+value+'/'+sid,
                dataType:'json',

                       error: function()
                {
                    alert('Error loading Data.');
                    //LOADER.hide(2000);
                },

                success: function(rs)
                {
                     jQuery("#unclockcodersource").html(Object(url));
                     //LOADER.hide(2000);

                } 
             });
    });
</script>
<div id="unclockcodersource"></div>
```

I want to show this data and save the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> jQuery("#unclockcodersource").text(rs);

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get particular attributes from JSON

> ```
>     success: function(rs)
>     {
>         $.each(rs.articles, function(index, ele){
>             alert(this.author);
>         });
>     }
> ```

or else

> ```
>     success: function(rs)
>     {
>         $.each(rs.articles, function(index,ele){
>             alert(ele.author);
>         });
>     }
> ```